# My QOpenGLWidget is being created, but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple form in which I add an OpenGLWidget, and then set my "MyOpenGLWidget" class to the Promoted Class,
[image: Скриншот 28-01-2021 161103.png]
it is successfully created, but is not displayed.
Its constructor is called, but the initializeGL, resizeGL, and paintGL functions are not called.
[image: 3443c732-ed35-489b-8866-aa426e641184-image.png]

Here is all my code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**ui_mainwindow.h**

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    MyOpenGLWidget *openGLWidget;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(420, 300);
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        openGLWidget = new MyOpenGLWidget(centralwidget);
        openGLWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("openGLWidget"));
        openGLWidget->setGeometry(QRect(60, 50, 300, 200));
        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**myopenglwidget.cpp**

```
#include "myopenglwidget.h"
#include "globalvars.h"
#include "gl/GLU.h"

MyOpenGLWidget::MyOpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent)
{
    qInfo() << "MyOpenGLWidget called";
}

MyOpenGLWidget::~MyOpenGLWidget()
{
    qInfo() << "~MyOpenGLWidget called";
}

void MyOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qInfo() << "initializeGL called!";
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    globalOpenGLContext = this->context();
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-this->width() / 2, this->width() / 2, -this->height() / 2, this->height() / 2);
    glViewport(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());

}

void MyOpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    qInfo() << "resizeGL called!";
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-w / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, h / 2);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void MyOpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    qInfo() << "paintGL called!";
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(-100, 100, 0);
    glVertex3f(100, 100, 0);
    glVertex3f(100, -100, 0);
    glVertex3f(-100, -100, 0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    update();
}
```

**myopenglwidget.h**

```
#ifndef MYOPENGLWIDGET_H
#define MYOPENGLWIDGET_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <qopenglfunctions_3_3_core.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

class MyOpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyOpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyOpenGLWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
};

#endif // MYOPENGLWIDGET_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> #include "gl/GLU.h"
> ```

This is not portable and, in particular, doesn't compile on Linux. The proper include is `<GL/glu.h>`.

> ```
> MyOpenGLWidget::MyOpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent)
> {
>    qInfo() << "MyOpenGLWidget called";
> }
> ```

You ignore the `parent` parameter, thus leaving your widget a *window*, rather than a child of its parent. But then you don't call `QWidget::show()` on it, so this separate window remains invisible, unlike the main window.

> ```
> #include <qopenglfunctions_3_3_core.h>
> ```

It's not the public header. You should include `<QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>` instead.

> ```
>    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
>    glVertex3f(-100, 100, 0);
>    glVertex3f(100, 100, 0);
>    glVertex3f(100, -100, 0);
>    glVertex3f(-100, -100, 0);
>    glEnd();
> ```

Given that you include OpenGL 3.3 Core functions header, these long-obsolete functions aren't supposed to be used. They don't exist in OpenGL Core profile.

Moreover, just calling them as this, directly, ignores the `QOpenGLOpenGLFunctions...` class completely. You should get an instance of this class from OpenGL context and call its methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an extended answer.
I'll take these mistakes into account.
Extremely grateful.